# getting error of Videoplayercontroller was used after being disposed in flutter when pressed back button

Tags: flutter, video

I am playing only one video in fullscreen landscape mode using Chewie video package. I am getting issue of videoplayercontroller was used after being disposed when i press back button of mobile. Firstly i disposed my chewiecontroller and then dispose videocontroller in dispose method but still i getting this issue. I don't able to find what is the problem so i get the error on back button pressed.Below is my code...

```
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

import 'package:newrit/main.dart';
import 'package:wakelock/wakelock.dart';

class StoryVideoPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String video_url;

  const StoryVideoPlayer({Key key, this.video_url}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _StoryVideoPlayerState createState() => _StoryVideoPlayerState(video_url);
}

class _StoryVideoPlayerState extends State<StoryVideoPlayer> {
  final String video_url;
  _StoryVideoPlayerState(this.video_url);

  VideoPlayerController controller;
  ChewieController _chewieController;


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Wakelock.enable();

    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);

    print('video_url: $video_url');
    controller = VideoPlayerController.network(video_url);

    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
      checkVideo();
    });

    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: controller,
      allowFullScreen: false,
      allowMuting: false,
      fullScreenByDefault: true,
      looping: false,
      autoPlay: true,
      allowedScreenSleep: false,
      deviceOrientationsAfterFullScreen: const [
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    ]);

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: (){
        Navigator.pop(context, true);
      },
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            children: <Widget>[
              Chewie(
                controller: _chewieController,
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: FractionalOffset.topLeft,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, top: 15.0),
                  child: Material(
                    type: MaterialType.transparency, //Makes it usable on any background color, thanks @IanSmith
                    child: Ink(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 4.0),
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      ),
                      child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0,5.0,7.0,5.0),
                            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                              size: useMobileLayout ? 22.0 : 35.0, color: Colors.white,),
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void checkVideo() {
    if(controller.value.position == Duration(seconds: 0, minutes: 0, hours: 0)) {
    }

    if(controller.value.position == controller.value.duration) {
      print('video Ended');
    }
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    _dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _dispose() async{
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    _chewieController.dispose();
    await controller.dispose();
    Wakelock.disable();
  }
}
```

Comment: any solutions ?

Comment: No, I didn't get the solution for this so I have design my own videocontroller. I didn't use chewiecontroller.